# Spotify Apps API: Detect offline mode

Tags: javascript, offline, spotify

Is there some way to detect whether Spotify is in Offline mode? I am currently developing an app which clearly depends on a working internet connection. I would like to be able to detect whether there is a connection to the internet at all and if not, show an error message.

I have found some general solutions for javascript which did not seem to work, like:

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it in the newer (2013+) 1.0 API:

```
 models.session.addEventListener('change:online',function({
    console.log('online =',models.session.online);
});
```

See https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-session.html for more info.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect if the client is offline by accessing the state in the session object.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/a5a59ca068.html

What you need to do is listen to the state change using the observer and look for the OFFLINE state.

```
DISCONNECTED: 2
DUMMY_USER: 4
LOGGED_IN: 1
LOGGED_OUT: 0
OFFLINE: 3

var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

models.session.observe(models.EVENT.STATECHANGED, function() {
    console.log(models.session.state);
});
```

Comment: Why isn't these things live yet on thes site? Very old things is still persent, the interaction guidelines is still demonstrating use of the sp.core!

Comment: Clicking the link above forces me to the main page of http://developer.spotify.com/

Comment: This is a more recent link to the documentation for the Session object. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/a5a59ca068.html

Comment: Now I saw it. Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/group__session.html
```

Checking

```
sp_connectionstate
```

for the enum value:

```
SP_CONNECTION_STATE_OFFLINE
```

Should get you what you want.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I'm not talking about libspotify, but the Spotify Apps API: http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/

Answer (score 0):

For Apps API V1 you would do something along the lines of...

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {

  // add a listener to pick up any changes in on / offline state
  models.session.addEventListener('change', changeOffline);

  function changeOffline(){
    var online = models.session.online; // returns true / false
    if(!online){
      // show offline message etc...
    } else {
      // hide offline message etc...
    }
  }
});
```

https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models-session.html